# Append View with data from firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I'm currently working with an app that gives tinder like card swiping ability and i stumbled upon a problem.

As i understand the code creates a card like an object, but i want it to create a card for each fetched user in the firebase database. Im using the Firebase RTDB.

The current code looks like this:

```
@State var cardViews: [CardView] = {
var views = [CardView]()
  
for index in 0..<2 {
  views.append(CardView())
}
return views
}()
```

The CardView:

```
 struct CardView: View, Identifiable {
 let id = UUID()

 var body: some View {
  VStack{
  KFImage.url(URL(string: ""))
      
                      .loadDiskFileSynchronously()
                      .cacheMemoryOnly()
                      .fade(duration: 0.25)
                      .onProgress { receivedSize, totalSize in  }
                      .onSuccess { result in }
                      .loadImmediately()
                      .onFailure { error in }
                      .resizable()
                      .scaledToFill()
  }
  .frame(width: 375, height: 600)
  .cornerRadius(24)
  .overlay(
    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 12) {
      Text("")
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        .font(.largeTitle)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .shadow(radius: 1)
        .padding(.horizontal, 18)
        .padding(.vertical, 4)
        .overlay(
          Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .frame(height: 1),
          alignment: .bottom
      )
      Text("".uppercased())
        .foregroundColor(Color.black)
        .font(.footnote)
        .fontWeight(.bold)
        .frame(minWidth: 85)
        .padding(.horizontal, 10)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .background(
          Capsule().fill(Color.white)
        )
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 280)
    .padding(.bottom, 50),
    alignment: .bottom
   )
}
}
```

My question is how can i use for (because foreach apparently isn't an option here to append the cardview with each entry from firebase fetched?

I'm currently fetching the users like so:

```
func fetchCandidates(){
    ref.child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        guard let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]  else { return}
            var user = UserData()
        
        if let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "employment")
                                  .childSnapshot(forPath: "employed").value as? 
String {
            
            
            user.email = (dictionary["email"] as! String)
            user.name = (dictionary["name"] as! String)
            user.firstname = (dictionary["firstname"] as! String)
            user.lastname = (dictionary["lastname"] as! String)
            user.type = (dictionary["type"] as! String)
            user.uid = snapshot.key
            user.profileImageUrl = (dictionary["profileImageUrl"] as! String)
            user.id = snapshot.key
            user.phone = (dictionary["phone"] as! String)
            user.onboarding = (dictionary["onboarding"] as! Bool)
            user.emailverified = (dictionary["emailverified"] as! Bool)
            user.identityverified = (dictionary["identityverified"] as! Bool)
            user.verificationstatus = (dictionary["verificationstatus"] as! String)
        
            print("Candidate: \(user)")
        
            self.candidates.append(user)
            }
          
            
        }
}
```

Thank you very much for all the help!!

Comment: - *As i understand the code creates a card like an object* - does that mean you didn't write the code and are adapting someone else's? Also, it appears you're populating an array *candidates* from Firebase but... You're not using it anywhere else in your code. The code really needs some clarity for us to understand both the question and the purpose of the code. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There is an EnviromentalObject that calls the functions and stores data there. I've been scrathing my head, because if a try to add @ ObservedObject inside that @ State object, i get different kinds of error, feels like that is not allowed to be done :D

Comment: The question is very confusing. It's tagged as Firebase but you're not doing anything with the retrieved data from Firebase. This really sounds like it's just a SwiftUI question; - "how do I add views to my UI" - because that's what you're doing. I suggest removing Firebase from the question and tag, and just focus on getting your views to display. Once you have that under control, add Firebase back in and let us know if you get stuck with that. e.g. there's nothing wrong with your Firebase code.